# Azure Container Appsの価格が良く分からないので教えて下さい

Tags: azure

https://azure.microsoft.com/ja-jp/pricing/details/container-apps/
にあるAzure Container Appsの価格を見ています。

ドキュメントのここ
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/container-apps/containers
を見るとAzure Container Appsには従量課金プラン（A）、ワークロードプロファイル従量課金プラン（B）、ワークロードプロファイルDedicated プラン（C）の３つがあるようですが
しかし上記のURLにはプランが２つしか記載されておらず従量課金プランとDedicated プランしか書かれておらず３つとの対応関係がよく分かりません。
なぜ３プランの記載がないでしょうか？このURLに書いてある「従量課金プラン」とは（A）と（B）どちらのことなのでしょうか？また書かれていない側の料金はどこを見れば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: 「３つあるようですが」はどこを参照しての情報でしょうか？

Comment: ここです　https://qiita.com/chappy7121/items/773b94072c93c543f3ec

Comment: あとここも「従量課金プラン」「専用プランで従量課金ワークロード プロファイル」「専用プラン」の3つが記載されていますね。
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/container-apps/containers

> 従量課金プラン では、値は次の規則に従う必要があります。
> 
> •ゼロより大きい
> • 2 以下
> • 任意の 10 進数 (小数点以下 2 桁まで) を指定
> 
> たとえば、1.25 は有効ですが、1.555 は無効です。
> 既定値は、コンテナーあたり 0.25 CPU です。
> 
> 専用プランで従量課金ワークロード プロファイルを使用する場合は、CPU が 4 以下
> である必要がある点を除き、同じ規則が適用されます。
> 
> 専用プラン を使用する場合、最大 CPU は、コンテナー アプリが実行されている
> プロファイルで使用可能なコアの数以下である必要があります。

Comment: こちらのページの方が基本なのでは？ [Azure Container Apps プランの種類](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/container-apps/plans) `Azure Container Apps には、2 種類のプランがあります。`と書かれています。Qiitaの記事での命名ではなくAzureのページを元に考えましょう。そしてページの言語を英語にすると`専用`の項目名は`Dedicated`と記述されています。質問記事やコメントで参照しているAzureのページも英語にしてみると区別が付くでしょう。あと参照記事や御自身でコメントに引用されているように、`専用プランで従量課金ワークロード プロファイルを使用する場合は、CPU が 4 以下である必要がある点を除き、同じ規則が適用されます。`とあるので、`従量課金ワークロードプロファイル`を使用するか否か(や割り当てる資源の量)で変わるのでは？

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございました。